# The asymptotic series plot is empty

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot the graph for this asymptotic series `a_k = -k!(-x)**(k+1)`, with `x=8`, for `k = 0,1,2,3......20`, but my graph has no points in it.
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import factorial

k = np.linspace(0.0, 30.0, 10)
a_k = -factorial(k)*(-8)**(k+1)

plt.semilogy(k,a_k,'b-')
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.ylabel("a_k")
plt.title("Asymptotic series with x = 8")
plt.show()
```

Comment: 5th line: should be negative(k+1)

Comment: Should `-factorial(k)*(-8)**(k+1)` be `-1 * factorial(k)*(-8)**(k+1)`? Not sure about where the parenthesis need to go, so it's either `( -1 * factorial(k)*(-8) )**(k+1)` or `-1 * ( factorial(k)*(-8) )**(k+1)`.

Comment: No, it's      -1 * factorial(k) * (-8) to the power of (k+1)

Comment: Where should the parenthesis go? Which part is being raised to the power of (k+1)? Everything before that? (That's what I suggested in my first alternative.)

Comment: Did you try looking at the output of your *a_k* array?  

Several values are returning NA because you're taking a root of a negative number.

Further, your *k* vector isn't populated with values from 0 to 20 in increments of 1 as you described.  Please reassess.